# Change image according to touch dragged

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

[image: Spritesheet]
this one is my sprite sheet i want to change the image according to user moves his finger on the screen
i.e, when he is touches the finger near this bow which is displayed initially no2 image from sprite sheet must be displayed, as he goes on dragging his finger according images must be displayed on screen
can anyone please guide me on this scenario because i totally don't know from where i must start.
thanks in advance
this is how i am displaying first image from sprite sheet

```
danceSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"bowspritesheet.png"];
        [self addChild:danceSheet z:1];

        danceSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:danceSheet.texture rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 140)];
        danceSprite.rotation=-90;
        danceSprite.position=ccp(screenSize.width/1.2, screenSize.height/6);
        [danceSheet addChild:danceSprite z:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to make one variable that tells you that is the maximum distance user can stretch. Beyond that if he stretch , there will be no effect on the bow. Suppose that distance as **30 pixels**.

Now you can implement your functionality using cctouchbegun method and cctouchmoved method. In cctouch method you have to set one ccpoint variable which will store the **first location user touched**. Suppose that as **firstLocation**. Simultaneously, you change the sprite of your bow to no.2 image.

Now, you have to work in ccmoved function. In that as user moved his fingure you will get current position where user has touched right now. So you have to get the distance and devide it by (30/10) that is 3. Suppose **(your distance/3)= 1** then you don't need to change the image of the bow. Now if it is equal to 2 then you have to change the bow wiht no.(2+1=)3 image. SO From this way you can implement bow functionality.*Here we did (30/10) because you have set maximum distance user can stretch is equal to 30 and you have 10 different image of bow with arrow.*

Hope, you get this,.If you find any difficulty in implementing this you can as me.

Comment: thanks for help  but how can i change the image from sprite sheet,can u give me some sample code..

Comment: can you tell me how did you put first image?

Comment: i have edited the question and put the code of displaying first image from sprite sheet

Comment: You have used spritesheet. So, You can directly get the texture of the other sprite using there name.You can change texture of the sprite using danceSprite =[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:"nameofthesprite"]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want some arrow animation using this given sprite-sheet, and you might want like when you swipe backwards from middle of your bow weapon then you want to launch your arrow.  Right ?!  you can use this sprite-sheet ,i guess what you have to do is just calculate or assume some distance. and  as i am showing your this sprite-sheet , you have around 10 images for launching arrow  action. so what you have to do is just put all those images at some equal distance according to your touch location ... i.e if you have 30px distance then you can put all your images according to your touch at 3px position. means you will start with your initial image at 0px  & then put all other images at 0 -3 -6 -9 & so on.. so this way you might achieve this. I hope my this try help you .. ask me if you don't get my answer at any point.